# Backbone-Relational doesn't work through ajax

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

Backbone-relation does not work when BackboneCollection takes data from uri, but when BackboneCollection takes data from javascript object - all right.

does not works when

```
var rows = new Rows();
rows.fetch();
```

but works if:

```
var Data = [{id: 1, cells: [column: 'name', value: 'some name']}];
var rows = new Rows(Data);
```

Use:

```
jquery 1.10.2
underscore 1.5.2
backbone 1.0.0
backbone-relational 0.8.6
```

[more here](http://jsfiddle.net/Stray/HSj8s/)

Comment: Are you sure that your backend returns what you think it does? ;)

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely sure